# how to store enum as tinyint in mysql with r2dbc

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jackson, r2dbc

I am working with Spring [WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html) and [r2dbc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/).

I have an entity with an enum field, and I would like to store it as tinyint in mysql while serializing as string.

// Order.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table("orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    Long id;

    StatusEnum status;
}
```

// StatusEnum.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum StatusEnum {
    PENDING(11),
    IN_PROGRESS(12),
    SUCCESSFUL(13),
    FAILED(14),

    UNKNOWN(255);

    final int value;
}
```

// sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    status TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 255
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

// API result for e.g. `GET /api/orders`

```
[
    { "id": 1, "status": "PENDING" },
    { "id": 2, "status": "IN_PROGRESS" },
    { "id": 3, "status": "SUCCESSFUL" },
    { "id": 4, "status": "FAILED" }
]
```

It reported error when inserting records:

```
Incorrect integer value: 'PENDING' for column 'status' at row 1; nested exception is io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcNonTransientResourceException
```

How can I resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I've got the same issue